Repeat an equation in Latex
I would like to repeat an equation somewhere in a document, let's say a = b+c. The equation appears at the beginning of the document, and I want to repeat it at the end to remind the readers. A simple way is to copy the equations manually, but it is easy to forget to change one while changing the other, which may incur inconsistency. Is there any automatic way to implement that?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The equation appears for the first time.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
a = b + c.
\end{equation}

The equation appears again.
\begin{equation}
a = b + c. \tag{\ref{eq:test}}
\end{equation}
Can we copy the equation from the very beginning?

\end{document}

Of course, I could try to define my own command by \newcommand in the preamble. However, writing equations before the document makes the preamble messy. I am look for a clearer way to do that.
To repeat a theorem, we could use restatble environment (c.f. the answer from @egreg). But I can't use it for align or equation environments. Is there any similar way to do that?

Welcome to TeX.SE.

\newcommand directives aren't limited to the preamble.

Thank you guy! It solves my problem to some extent.

It would be better if I could use my new command before I define it. For example, sometimes, I need to prove a theorem containing a complicated equation, which appears in both the description and the proof. The proof is usually placed after the description. If I could edit the equation in the proof and repeat it in the description, it would become more convenient for me.

I found @John Kormylo posts a solution with \savebox, I think I could be another solution for that.

If you want to support repetition of equations that appear later, you need to exploit the .aux file.
With \saveequation the equation is typeset and also stored in the .aux file. At the next run \repeatequation will be able to retypeset the same math material.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\saveequation}[2]{% #1 = label, #2 = math
  #2 \label{#1}
  \protected@write\@mainaux{}{\string\SAVEEQUATION{#1}{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#2}}}}%
}
\newcommand{\SAVEEQUATION}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{SAVEDEQUATION@#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\repeatequation}[1]{%
  \ifcsname SAVEDEQUATION@#1\endcsname
    \@nameuse{SAVEDEQUATION@#1}\tag{\ref{#1}}%
  \else
    ?? \notag
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The equation appears for the first time.
\begin{equation}
\saveequation{eq:test}{a = b + c}
\end{equation}

The equation appears again.
\begin{equation}
\repeatequation{eq:test}
\end{equation}

This instead appears earlier than the real equation
\begin{equation}
\repeatequation{eq:later}
\end{equation}

And now the one we want to show also earlier
\begin{equation}
\saveequation{eq:later}{p+q=r}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

Here's the contents of the .aux file:
\relax 
\SAVEEQUATION{eq:test}{a = b + c}
\newlabel{eq:test}{{1}{1}{}{equation.1}{}}
\SAVEEQUATION{eq:later}{p+q=r}
\newlabel{eq:later}{{2}{1}{}{equation.2}{}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}



Thank you guy! It really works and solves my problem

While writing the code for keytheorems I also wrote some code for recording and repeating semi-arbitrary content (no weird catcodes!), including before the original code. It has several bells and whistles that take a lot of inspiration from the scontents package. Here it is applied to your use-case. Note the use of writefile so the environment contents can be used before being stated and counters={equation,theorem} so it knows to store and use the original counters.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{recordenv}

\recenvset{writefile,counters={equation,theorem}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

First let's state our main theorem.
\getrecenv{nicethm}

\begin{theorem}
Some normal theorem with a normal equation.
\begin{equation}
i+j=k
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

Some equation:
\begin{recordenv}[tag=someeq]
\begin{equation}
a+b=c
\end{equation}
\end{recordenv}

\begin{recordenv}[tag=nicethm]
\begin{theorem}[My nice theorem]
Some really nice theorem text.

Let's repeat the equation:
\getrecenv{someeq}
\end{theorem}
\end{recordenv}

\end{document}



This does not have extensive testing so use at your own risk!
\ProvidesExplPackage{recordenv}{2024-02-01}{0.0.0alpha}
  {Record environment contents}

\msg_new:nnn { recordenv } { no-stored-env }
  {
    No~stored~content~'#1'~found!~
    \bool_if:NTF \g__recenv_makeextfile_bool
      {
        Try~compiling~again.~If~that~doesn't~work,~
        check~the~spelling~of~'#1'.
      }
      { Check~the~spelling~of~'#1'.}
  }
\msg_new:nnn { recordenv } { no-seq-exists }
  {
    No~sequence~'#1'~exists!
  }

\bool_new:N \g__recenv_makeextfile_bool
\bool_gset_false:N \g__recenv_makeextfile_bool
\clist_new:N \l__recenv_counters_clist
\hook_new:n { recenv/pre }
\hook_new:n { recenv/post }
\int_new:N \l__recenv_foreach_int
\iow_new:N \g__recenv_iow
\prop_new:N \l__recenv_counters_prop
\prop_new:N \l__recenv_tmpa_prop
\seq_new:N \g__recenv_name_default_seq
\tl_new:N \l__recenv_tmpa_tl

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn { c }

\keys_define:nn { recenv }
  {
    seq           .tl_set:N           = \l__recenv_seq_tl,
    seq           .initial:n          = default,
    tag           .tl_set:N           = \l__recenv_tag_tl,
    tag           .initial:n          = {},
    print         .bool_set:N         = \l__recenv_print_bool,
    print         .initial:n          = true,
    hide          .bool_set_inverse:N = \l__recenv_print_bool,
    expand        .bool_set:N         = \l__recenv_expand_bool,
    expand        .initial:n          = false,
    replacehashes .bool_set:N         = \l__recenv_replacehashes_bool,
    replacehashes .initial:n          = false,
    counters      .code:n             =
      {
        \clist_set:Nn \l__recenv_counters_clist { #1 }
        \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__recenv_counters_clist
          { \tl_clear_new:c { l__recenv_current_##1_tl } }
      },
    counters*     .code:n             =
      {
        \clist_put_right:Nn \l__recenv_counters_clist { #1 }
        \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
          { \tl_clear_new:c { l__recenv_current_##1_tl } }
      },
    writefile     .bool_set:N = \l__recenv_writefile_bool,
    writefile     .initial:n = false,
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \recenvset { m } { \keys_set:nn { recenv } { #1 } }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { recordenv } { O{} +b }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { recenv } { #1 }
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__recenv_counters_clist
      {
        \prop_put:Nne \l__recenv_counters_prop { ##1 } { \the\value{##1} }
      }
    \bool_if:NTF \l__recenv_expand_bool
      {
        \protected@edef \l__recenv_tmpa_tl { #2 }
      }
      {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__recenv_tmpa_tl { #2 }
      }
    \bool_if:NT \l__recenv_replacehashes_bool
      {
        \regex_replace_all:nnN { \cP\# } { \cO\# } \l__recenv_tmpa_tl
      }
    \bool_if:NT \l__recenv_writefile_bool
      {
        \bool_gset_true:N \g__recenv_makeextfile_bool
      }
    \seq_if_exist:cF { g__recenv_name_ \l__recenv_seq_tl _seq }
      {
        \seq_new:c { g__recenv_name_ \l__recenv_seq_tl _seq }
      }
    \__recenv_addtoseq:VeV \l__recenv_tag_tl
      {
        \prop_to_keyval:N \l__recenv_counters_prop
      }
      \l__recenv_tmpa_tl
    \cs_if_exist:cF { __recenv_deffromfile_ \l__recenv_tag_tl _marker }
      {
        \tl_if_empty:NF \l__recenv_tag_tl
          {
            \__recenv_define:neV { \l__recenv_tag_tl }
              {
                \prop_to_keyval:N \l__recenv_counters_prop
              }
              \l__recenv_tmpa_tl
          }
      }
    \bool_if:NT \l__recenv_print_bool { #2 }
  }
  {}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__recenv_addtoseq:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \seq_gput_right:cn { g__recenv_name_ \l__recenv_seq_tl _seq }
      {
        { #1 }
        { #2 }
        { #3 }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__recenv_addtoseq:nnn { VeV }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \RecordEnvDefFromFile #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nF { #1 }
      {
        \cs_new:cpn { __recenv_deffromfile_#1_marker } { }
        \__recenv_define:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__recenv_define:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_const:cn { c__recenv_getenv_#1_tl }
      { \__recenv_print:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__recenv_define:nnn { neV }

\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument } { . }
  {
    \makeatletter % in case 'expand' leads to @'s
    \file_if_exist_input:n { \c_sys_jobname_str.record }
    \makeatother
  }

\hook_gput_code:nnn { enddocument } { . }
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \g__recenv_makeextfile_bool
      {
        \iow_open:Nn \g__recenv_iow { \c_sys_jobname_str.record }
        \seq_map_function:NN \g__recenv_name_default_seq \__recenv_recorddef_aux:n
        \iow_close:N \g__recenv_iow
      }
      { % if .record file left over from previous run but not needed, clear it
        \file_if_exist:nT { \c_sys_jobname_str.record }
          {
            \iow_open:Nn \g__recenv_iow { \c_sys_jobname_str.record }
            \iow_close:N \g__recenv_iow
          }
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__recenv_recorddef_aux:n #1
  {
    \iow_now:Nn \g__recenv_iow
      {
        \RecordEnvDefFromFile #1
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \getrecenv { O{} m }
  {
    \tl_if_exist:cTF { c__recenv_getenv_#2_tl }
      {
        \group_begin:
        \keys_set:nn { recenv/get } { #1 }
        \tl_use:c { c__recenv_getenv_#2_tl }
        \group_end:
      }
      {
        \textbf{??}
        \msg_warning:nnn { recordenv } { no-stored-env } { #2 }
      }
  }

\keys_define:nn { recenv/foreach }
  {
    sep .tl_set:N = \l__recenv_foreach_sep_tl,
    sep .initial:n = {},
    before .tl_set:N = \l__recenv_foreach_before_tl,
    before .initial:n = {},
    after .tl_set:N = \l__recenv_foreach_after_tl,
    after .initial:n = {},
    print-code .cs_set:Np = \__recenv_foreach_printcmd:n #1,
    print-code .initial:n = #1,
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \foreachrecenv { O{} m }
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cTF { g__recenv_name_#2_seq }
      {
        \group_begin:
        \keys_set:nn { recenv/foreach } { #1 }
        \int_set:Nn \l__recenv_foreach_int
          {
            \seq_count:c { g__recenv_name_#2_seq }
          }
        \seq_map_indexed_inline:cn { g__recenv_name_#2_seq }
          {
            \l__recenv_foreach_before_tl
            \__recenv_foreach_printcmd:n
              { \__recenv_printfromseq_aux:nnn ##2 }
            \l__recenv_foreach_after_tl
            \int_compare:nNnF { ##1 } = { \l__recenv_foreach_int }
              { \l__recenv_foreach_sep_tl }
          }
        \group_end:
      }
      {
        \msg_error:nnn { recordenv } { no-seq-exists } { #2 }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__recenv_printfromseq_aux:nnn #1#2#3
  { \__recenv_print:nn { #2 } { #3 } }

\hook_gput_code:nnn { recenv/pre } { default }
  {
    \renewcommand\label[2][]{} % disable \label (opt arg in case cleveref loaded)
    \cs_set_eq:NN \ltx@label \use_none:n % disable \ltx@label
    \cs_set_eq:NN \property_record:nn \use_none:nn % disable \RecordProperties
  }

\newcounter{recenv_dummyctr}
\cs_gset:Npn \theHrecenv_dummyctr { record.\arabic{recenv_dummyctr} }
\cs_gset:Npn \therecenv_dummyctr { }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__recenv_print:nn #1#2
  { % #1 = counters, #2 = contents
    \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__recenv_tmpa_prop { #1 }
    \refstepcounter{recenv_dummyctr}
    \prop_map_inline:Nn \l__recenv_tmpa_prop
      {
        \tl_set:ce { l__recenv_current_##1_tl } { \the\value{##1} }
        \setcounter { ##1 } { ##2 }
        \cs_set:cpe { theH ##1 } { \exp_not:c { the ##1 } . \theHrecenv_dummyctr }
      }
    \hook_use:n { recenv/pre }
    #2
    \hook_use:n { recenv/post }
    \prop_map_inline:Nn \l__recenv_tmpa_prop
      {
        \exp_args:Nnv \setcounter { ##1 } { l__recenv_current_##1_tl }
      }
  }

\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument } { . }
  {
    \DeclareDocumentEnvironment { restatable } { o m m O{} +b }
      {
        \cs_if_exist:cT { c@ #2 }
          { \keys_set:nn { recenv } { counters*=#2 } }
        \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #1 }
          { 
            \begin{recordenv}[tag=#3,#4]
            \begin{#2}
          }
          {
            \begin{recordenv}[tag=#3,#4]
            \begin{#2}[#1]
          }
        #5
        \end{#2}
        \end{recordenv}
        \cs_if_free:cT { #3 }
          {
            \cs_new:cpn { #3 }
              { % make \foo and \foo* identical
                \peek_meaning_remove:NTF *
                  { \tl_use:c { c__recenv_getenv_#3_tl } }
                  { \tl_use:c { c__recenv_getenv_#3_tl } }
              }
          }
      }
      {}
  }
  
\file_input_stop:

